# Linq records to string array

Tags: c#, arrays, string, linq, linq-to-entities

This is my LINQ:

```
var context = new CYGNETEntities();
var users = (from u in context.mUsers
             where u.userName == EmailID && u.password == Password
             select new 
             { 
                 u.userName,  
                 u.firstName,  
                 u.lastName  
             })
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Select(x => string.Format("{0}, {1}, {2}", x.userName, x.firstName, x.lastName))
    .ToArray();
```

Here, the actual values are below:

```
   u.userName = "admin"
   u.firstName = "fname"
   u.lastName = "lname"
```

So, the linq returns as below:

```
users[0] = admin, fname, lname
```

But I want the linq records in string array such as below:

```
   users[0] = admin
   users[1] = fname
   users[2] = lname
```

Any suggestions please?

Comment: You can split the users array by comma, and you will get your result.

Comment: this has to be a 2-dimensional array in case that you have 2 results with the same `EmailID` and `Password`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tested this, but what about:

```
var users = (from u in context.mUsers
              where u.userName == EmailID && u.password == Password
              from s in new string [] { u.username, u.FirstName, u.LastName }
              select s).ToArray();
```

Comment: He's using a `SelectMany`, so he needs the `.ToArray()`.